# Dúvida em uma questão de ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro

A questão é essa:

Construa uma função que receba dois valores inteiros `a` e `b`, retorne (passagem por referência) o quociente, div, e o resto divisão, mod, de `a` por `b`. A função deve retornar `-1` caso não seja possível realizar as operações e `0` caso seja possível. Um algoritmo para utilizar tal função deve ser criado, tratando o retorno da função.

Eu fiz o código assim, mas não tenho a mínima ideia do que estou fazendo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int div (int *a, int *b)
{
    int resultado, resto, aux;
    if (*b==0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = (*a / *b);
        resto = (*a % *b);
        return 0;
    }
}
int main (void)
}

int a, b, *resto, *resultado, *aux;
printf ("Digite o valor do dividendo: ");
scanf ("%i", &a);
printf ("Digite o valor do divisor: ");
scanf("%i", &b);
div (&a, &b);
if (div == 0)
{
    printf ("O resultado da divisao eh: %i ", resultado);
    printf ("O resto da divisao eh: %i", resto);
}
else
{
    printf ("Nao eh possivel realizar uma divisao por 0");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O seu código está um tanto quanto bagunçado. Talvez a IDE estivesse colocando ora tabulação, ora espaçamento. Se você puder ajeitar o código ficaria muito mais fácil de ler

Comment: foi mal, primeira vez usando isso, eu nem sei como editar o post, vou procurar aqui...

Comment: Faça o [tour], lá boa parte de como você deve usar o site é explicado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> construa uma função que retorne 0 caso seja possível fazer a operação, -1 caso contrário

Aqui você fez bem, só não é possível fazer a divisão quando o denominador é 0.

Para fazer essa comparação, como o denominador é passado por referência, deve-se fazer `*var` para desreferenciar. No caso, estou considerando que `b` é sempre o denominador e `a` como numerador. Portanto, saber se é possível fazer a divisão é fazer a seguinte comparação:

```
*b == 0
```

> deve retornar o quociente e o resto por referência

Aqui começa a bagunça ;-)

Eu, que gosto de trabalhar com memória a rodo e só otimizar quando encontra um gargalo, iria passar dois parâmetros adicionais. A assinatura da função ficaria assim:

```
int div(int *a, int *b, int *quociente, int *mod);
```

Pensando nesse esquema, a atribuição de `quociente` e `mod` seriam feitas assim:

```
int va = *a; // guarda o valor de a para ficar mais limpa a manipulação 
int vb = *b; // idem para b

*quociente = va/vb;
*mod = va%vb;
```

Mas como eu creio que a intenção seria retornar sobre `a` e `b` o resultado dessa operação, então não se poderia alterar a assinatura da função:

```
int div(int *a, int *b);
```

Para armazenar os valores da divisão e do módulo sem destruir os valores apontados por `a` e `b`, seria necessário guardar uma cópia desses valores. Ficaria assim para receber os valores via `a` e `b` e retornar também via `a` e `b`:

```
int va = *a; // guarda o valor de a para ficar mais limpa a manipulação 
int vb = *b; // idem para b

*a = va/vb;
*b = va%vb;
```

O resto do código me parece correto a primeira vista.